# Show more config react big calendar

Tags: calendar, limit, show, monthcalendar, react-big-calendar

How to change limiting of show more events in view Month on react big calendar?
I want to have "2 show more" in month view of react-big-calendar.
Actually, I have "3 show more" and plus.

Answer (score 0):

How many are displayed in the 'date cell' is dependent upon the height you have given to the parent container around your Calendar. The Calendar will display as many items as it can with a '+x Show More' link, with 'x' being however many more events you have on that day. Or you can use the new `showAllEvents` boolean prop to have the calendar put them all in a scrollable 'date cell'. (The documentation site is not yet updated for this prop, though you can see the new docs by cloning the repo and running the 'examples')

Answer (score -1):

Just add `showAllEvents` boolean prop to have the calendar put them all in a scrollable 'date cell'.